# Java PDFBox addPage produce blank pages

Tags: java, pdfbox

I try to create a PDF Document merging all my PDFs files and between each page of each file a fixed PDPage

```
// Create final PDF Document
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

// List all pdf files input folder
String[] filenames;
File f = new File(context.repertoire_output_docone);
filenames = f.list();

// Get the PDF page 
File cgv = new File(context.repertoire_advendio + "conf/CGV.pdf");
PDDocument doccgv = Loader.loadPDF(cgv);
PDPage cgvpage = doccgv.getPage(0);

// For each pdf file found
for (String filename : filenames)
{
    // If name doens't match the template, skip
    if (filename.startsWith("fact_") == false && filename.startsWith("agence_fact_") == false)
        continue;

    // Open current document
    PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(new File(context.repertoire_output_docone + filename));
    
    // For each page of the current document
    for (PDPage page : doc.getPages())
    {
        // Add page
        document.addPage(page);

        // Add fixed page
        document.addPage(cgvpage);
    }
}

// Save final document
document.save(context.repertoire_output_docone + "output/docone_" + context.id_legal_entity + "_" + context.input_invoice_date.replace("-", "") + ".pdf");

// Close final document
document.close();
```

This code produce a PDF with only full blank pages. It goes in the loops, I have the good number of pages in the final document (so the pages are added) but it's just blank pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`importPage`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#importPage(org.apache.pdfbox.pdfmodel.PDPage)) instead of [`addPage`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#addPage(org.apache.pdfbox.pdfmodel.PDPage)).

`importPage`'s Javadoc says:

> This will import and copy the contents from another location [...] If you are adding a page to this document from another document and want to copy the contents to this document's scratch file then use this method otherwise just use the `addPage(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage)` method.